# What new features does GTK+3.0 introduce?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

And how will it improve other GTK themes such as Ambiance or Elementary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GTK+ 3 release notes gave the basics of it.
GTK+ 3.x will not directly change/improve themes like Ambiance, in fact, most of these themes won't work as yet, as they have to be ported.

However, you can expect to see some improvements all around as things progress with GTK+ 3.x.

**This answer is now outdated, and needs an update.*

Comment: The provided link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

> GTK+ 3 is a major new version of GTK+, containing far too many changes to list them all here. The major highlights include:
>
> - Cairo drawing throughout. GDK no longer wraps the antiquated   X11 drawing API; we've made a clean break and exclusively rely   on cairo
>     for all our drawing needs now. This has also enabled us   to remove
>     several other X11-centric concepts such as GCs, colormaps   and
>     pixmaps.
> - Modern input device handling. The input device handling in GDK has   long been a sadly neglected area. This has changed; with 3.0, GTK+ steps into the modern world of XI2 with full support for multiple pointers, keyboards and other gizmos.
> - A new theming API which sports a familiar CSS syntax for theme   configuration and other improvements such as animated state transitions.
> - More flexible geometry management, with support for height-for-width,   for both widgets and cell renderers.
> - Multiple backend support for GDK. With GTK+ 2.x, you had to recompile   your application to have it work with a different GDK backend.   In GTK+ 3, multiple GDK backends can be built into a single library   and selected at runtime.
> - Easy application support. With the integration of D-Bus support in   GIO, we could finally add a GtkApplication class that handles a lot of the platform integration aspects of writing an application, such as keeping track of open windows, ensuring uniqueness, exporting actions, etc.
> - Of course, there's some new widgets as well, such as a switch and   an application chooser.

Source: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-announce-list/2011-February/msg00022.html

Comment: Missing however is support for resolution independence, which makes GTK3 effectively dead going forward.